# How do I bind to a customized button class?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create an extension of the basic XAML Button class that will take a settable and re-sizable `DataTemplate` as its content.  The goal is to not use a ControlTemplate so that I don't need to re-define all of the default Button states that XAML provides.

I've got a customized button class with basic `DependencyProperty`s like so:

```
// IconButton.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class IconButton : Button
{
    public readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(App.Current.Resources["PlaceholderSmiley"]));
    public readonly DependencyProperty IconSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconSize", typeof(double), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(20));

    public DataTemplate Icon
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public double IconSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(IconSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

}
```

And the XAML:

```
// IconButton.xaml
<Button
    x:Class="CustomControls.IconButton" 
    ... >

    <Viewbox Width="{Binding IconSize}" Height="{Binding IconSize}">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Icon}" />
    </Viewbox>

</Button>
```

And I invoke it like this:

```
<c:IconButton Height="60" Width="60" IconSize="20" Icon="{StaticResource Info}" />
```

Where Info is a `DataTemplate` containing a `Canvas` and one or more `Path`s.  However, neither my IconSize or the Icon itself are being populated on the finished button.  Is there a step I'm missing?

If I use these 5 lines code instead of the one line above, everything works perfectly, but using the derived class above would clean things up and keep them flexible:

```
<Button>
    <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Info}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't calling `this.InitializeComponent()` on construction.  Not sure how that line got deleted.  Additionally, the DependencyProperties needed to be `static`, or every icon except the last would only display its default value.